# change url where to render view with Express 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a post request the problem is that when I render my views it's rendered to `/link/123` wheras I want that view to render to `/anotherlink` 
I could've use `res.redirect ('/anotherlink')` but I need to render different data

```
 app.post('/link/:id',function (req, res, next){
   res.render('products', {
   data : 'help please'
   });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a better solution which is by changing the url in the view without reloading : `window.history.pushState("", "", '/wantedLink');`

Answer (score 0):

I found a turn arround about my problem so instead of `res.render`I've used `res.status(200).send('ok');` 
and then when the user clicks the submit button I've used an ajax form to send a modal with notification that update has been done

```
    $('#update-form').ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit :...
        },
        success : function(responseText, status, xhr, $form){
            if (status == 'success') $('.modal-alert').modal('show');
        },
        error : ...
    });
```

and when user clicks 'ok' he will be sent to  `/anotherlink`

```
   $('.modal-alert #ok').click(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = '/anotherlink';}, 200)});
    }
```